# Python Numpy get 2 Indexes which are not in a Blacklist

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Given a numpy-vector and a list of forbidden indexes. I need to return two indexes which are not in the list of forbidden indexes and both the values at the indexes are non zero and if this is not possible i need to return false.

```
a = np.matrix([[7885593,9648586,9182,14763,0]])
forbidden = [1,2]
```

So i need to return `[0,3]`
I thought about numpy.where() but this works only with values not with indexes.

Comment: have you tried working with an array of indices: `np.arange(a.shape(1))`?  Or a boolean like `np.ones((a.shape(1),),dtype=bool)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is vague in places, so I'm making some guesses as to what you want.

Boolean masks are a nice way of 'removing' items from an array.

```
i=np.ones(5,bool)    # array of True
i[[1,2]]=False       # falsify the forbidden ones
np.where(i)[0][:2]   # get the first 2 true indices
```

producing:

```
array([0, 3], dtype=int32)
```